# find location of web application running on windows PC

Tags: windows-10, webserver

I have been provided with a colleague's machine which had a web application hosted on it. The PC had to be restarted to complete updates but the web service has not come back up. I looked firstly in c:\inetpub\wwwroot for any indication of the folder/files and also check the task scheduler but no indication of where this service is deployed. I don't see any indication of apache/tomcat installed either.

Not wanting to look like an idiot in front of my network admin guy, I thought someone here may have ideas on how to find and restart this process.

http://192.xxx.x.xx:8080/monitorTool/

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Have you checked IIS manager? (Wwwroot is the default websites root, other sites can be located elsewhere on the system). Also check the services mmc snapin, it might be installed but as a windows service, but not set to run automatically.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your response. It displays the default web site and points back to the wwwroot folder. The services check is a good idea, would the service be named as the application or under which service should I check>

Comment: The displayname is set in the registry so if some server was added as a windows service it could be named anything (Presumably something easily identifiable?)